# How can I cast/extract nested column field from scala DataFrame to a case class most efficiently?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, case-class

I have a case class like :

**case class PA(
id: Long,
name: String,
level: Int,
.......,
path: Seq[ParentPath]
)**

and ParentPath class is like :

**case class ParentPath(level: Int, id: Long, name: String)**

Now When I getting back the DataFrame from Hive and casting a DF to PA,  I am getting exception,
class cast exception.
Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to com.abc.ParentPath
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)*
```

I am reading the Df like below:

```
    case Success(df) =>
      Some(df.map(row =>
        (row: @unchecked) match {
          case (r: GenericRowWithSchema) => PA(
              r.getAs[Long]("id"),
              r.getAs[String]("name"),
              r.getAs[Int]("level"),
              r.getAs[Seq[(Int, Long, String)]]("path").asInstanceOf[Seq[ParentPath]
            )
          case _ => null
```

What can be another way to cast the DF to get the inner case class data?